# Nuxt Middleware is not working on vue login

Tags: vue.js

I have a login page and I am applying NUXT middleware, it works fine when I am not logged in but after I logged in it doesn't work.I can redirect to login page after I logged in.
This is my login.vue

```
 <script>
    export default {
      middleware: 'auth',
      ...
      },
</script>
```

and this is my middleware/auth.js

```
export default function({ redirect }) {
  if (!process.server) {
    let token = localStorage.getItem('token')
    if (token) {
      return redirect('/')
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense to me. The middleware you got there will redirect the user to '/' if it finds a token in localStorage. I think you need to explain in detail what you want to happen.

Comment: yes, it should redirect to the '/' but it doesn't, it is redirecting to the '/login' page. I am using server-side rendering.

Comment: You want to redirect to '/' right after the user logs in?

Comment: after I logged in I am redirecting to 'localhost:3000', that works fine what I want, but the issue is that when I manual reload 'localhost/login' it goes back to the login page which I don't want, I want to redirect it to '/'.